# If $d$ is the integer which generates $a \mathbb Z + b \mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory

Michael Artin in Proposition 2.6 states:

> Let $a,b$ be integers not both zero, and let $d$ be the positive integer which generates the subgroup $a \mathbb Z +b \mathbb Z$ then

- $d$ can be written in the form of $ar+bs$
- $d$ divides both $a,b$
- If an integer $e$ divides $a$ and $b$, it also divides $d$

My questions:

1. How does the second proposition hold true for $a=2,b=7 , d=9$?
2. How do we prove this? (a slight hint may be sufficient)

Comment: $d$ is the positive integer that **generates** $\dots$. Definitely if $a=2$ and $b=7$ then $d\ne 9$. Indeed $d=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: It doesn't, but these three numbers don't satisfy the assumptions because $2\mathbb{Z}+7\mathbb{Z}$ isn't generated by $9$. (As pointed out slightly faster by Julian).

Question 2: This follows from the fact that $\{a,b\}\subset a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}$. (Here I have taken your second question to mean "how do we prove the second proposition?").

Answer (score 3):

$2\mathbb{Z}+7\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$, not $9\mathbb{Z}$:

$2\cdot (-3)+7\cdot (1)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I indeed checked it, and well... :) (sheepish smile)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The set $\rm\:S\:$ of integers of the form $\rm\:x\:a + y\:b,\ x,y\in \mathbb Z\:$ is closed under subtraction so, by the Lemma below, every $\rm\:n\in S\:$ is divisible by the least positive $\rm\:d\in S.\:$ Thus $\rm\:a,b\in S\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:d\:|\:a,b,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:d\:$ is a *common* divisor of $\rm\:a,b,\:$ necessarily *greatest,* by $\rm\:e\:|\:a,b\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:e\:|\: \hat x\:a+\hat y\:b = d\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:e\le d.$

**Lemma** $\ \ $ If a nonempty set of positive integers $\rm\: S\:$ satisfies $\rm\ n > m\ \in\ S \ \Rightarrow\ \: n-m\ \in\ S$ 
 then every element of $\rm\:S\:$ is a multiple of the least element $\rm\:m_{\:1} \in S.$

**Proof** $\ \: $ If not there is a least nonmultiple $\rm\:n\in S,\,$ contra  $\rm\:n-m_{\:1} \in S\:$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\:m_{\:1}.$

**Remark** $\ $ This fundamental lemma, interpreted procedurally, yields Euclid's classical algorithm to compute the gcd using only *repeated subtraction.*

This *linear* representation of the the gcd is known as the *Bezout identity* for the gcd. It need not hold true in all domains where gcds exist, e.g. in the domain $\rm\:D = \mathbb Q[x,y]\:$ of polynomials in $\rm\:x,y\:$ with rational coefficients we have $\rm\:gcd(x,y) = 1\:$ but there are no $\rm\:f(x,y),\: g(x,y)\in D\:$ such that $\rm\:x\:f(x,y) + y\:g(x,y) = 1;\:$ indeed, if so, then evaluating at $\rm\:x = 0 = y\:$ yields $\:0 = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you want to do. The first would be to show that $H=a\mathbb{Z} + b\mathbb{Z}$ contains positive integers and  let $S$, say, be the set of all positive integers in $H$. Use the well-ordering principle to obtain a least element of $S$ and call this least element $d$. Now, let $t=ar+bs \in H$. Write $t=qd+r, 0\leq r<d$, by the division algorithm. Note that $r=t-qd$ is in $H$, which is a contradiction unless $r=0$, whence $d$ divides $t$. Thus $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$ since each is is $H$.

If $e$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $e$ must divide $d$, since $d \in H$ and so can be written as $d=ar+bs$ for suitable $r$ and $s$.

In essence, you have just shown that $d$ is the greatest common divisor (or, highest common factor) of $a$ and $b$.