# If a and b generate groups of their own, then any linear combination of the integers, will also generate a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

sorry if the wording of the question was a little confusing. But I am confused by a theorem that was provided in my algebra textbook. There was a proposition which stated that:

**Theorem 1:** Let S be a subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Either S is the trivial subgroup {0}, or else it has the form, $\mathbb{Z}$ where a is the smallest positive integer in S.

This makes intuitive sense to me. Now, here is the proposition that is confusing to me:

Subgroups that contain two integers a, and b. (I am not sure how a subgroup can only contain two integers, first of all). The set of all integer combinations of ra + sb, of a and b,
$S = \mathbb{Z}a + \mathbb{Z}b = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}| n = ra + sb\}$for some integers r,s.
Why must this necessarily be true? I don't see any intuitive reason why any linear combination of the generators must be part of some subgroup?

Furthermore,it stated:

**Proposition** : Let a and b be integers both not 0, and let d be their greatest common divisor, the positive integer that generates the subgroup $S = \mathbb{Z}a + \mathbb{Z}b$. Why must this value d be the greatest common divisor? Can someone please help me understand the reasoning?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191962/if-d-is-the-integer-which-generates-a-mathbb-z-b-mathbb-z?rq=1) for the Proposition. It is explained there in detail.

Comment: The statement should be "has the form $a\mathbb{Z}$, where..." You are missing the $a$. "Subgroups that contain two integers" means that they contain *at least* two integers, not that they contain *exactly two* integers.